# After Upgrading Django from 1.3 to 1.4.3 Syncdb Fails to delete stale content types

Tags: python, django, content-type, syncdb

**How can I successfully delete the stale content?

Typing yes yields the following:**

```
Creating tables ...
```

The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

```
auth | message
```

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

```
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
...

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: 
(1146, "Table '<db_name>.auth_group_permissions' doesn't exist")
Process finished with exit code 1
```

**The other thing I tried was:**

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth',model='messages')
```

And I receive the following:

```
DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

and check all the tables created by you before.

See if **auth_group_permissions** exists. If it's not there, I guess you can manually create it and do the process again.

Comment: auth_group_permissions does not exist in the database.  How do I manually create it?

Comment: The issue turned out to be a database problem.  Somehow auth_group_permissions got dropped...  So I created a new database. I created a new django project. Ran syncdb. Then I ran the following commands under MYSQL as root 
USE <live_project_db>;
CREATE TABLE auth_group_permissions LIKE <new_db>.auth_group_permissions;

Answer (score 1):

The `model` field of the contenttype of the `auth.message` is `'message'` instead of `'messages'`.
so try

`ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth',model='message')`

You could then list `ct.permission_set.all()` or even run `ct.delete()` (in transaction and print relative objects to be deleted) to reproduce the issue.

Also, the error about 'missing table' is weird, can you check in DB whether the table really exists? Or do you have multiple DBs configured in 1.3?

Comment: Good catch on my typo.  However, when I run ct.delete() I'm still getting DatabaseError: (1146, "Table '<db_name>.auth_group_permissions' doesn't exist").  It turns out that this table does not exist when I took a look at my database, but I'm not sure how to create it.

Comment: When I run ct.permission_set.all() I get:
[<Permission: auth | message | Can add message>, <Permission: auth | message | Can change message>, <Permission: auth | message | Can delete message>]

Comment: I only have one database.  However, I have two separate projects that share the database. The projects do not share the same tables.

Comment: @nueverest it's fine you've solved it. Remember to backup important data when you need to manually operate DB. On localhost, you could safely remove and rebuild tables or whole DB.